# Why in this example do we need to use "working" in the gerund form after the verb "love"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

In the example below I believe do we need to use "working" in the gerund form?

> You will love working here

I thought that verbs following "love" can be either in the gerund form or the infinitive form, but for this example the infinitive form does not sound correct:

> You will love to work here

Is there a reason for this or is this second example also correct?

Comment: They are both correct.

Comment: The second sentence isn't natural. It might even be wrong. Can't put my finger on why.

Comment: @gotube - "I would love to work here" is fine, though, isn't it? Perhaps it sounds odd with 
 _you will_ because _working_ refers to the experience rather than the opportunity.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, "*I **would** love to work here*" is fine. That's a workable theory, but I haven't come up with contrasting example sentences that convince me it's true.

Comment: They are clearly not both correct… 

'You will love working…' is correct but 'You will love to work…' is not equivalent.

I was about to explain "I would love to work here" when I saw Kate Bunting's and gotube's Posts… Go, Kate!

At best, you need 'You might/would love to…'

If it helps, the difference is between 'You will…' and 'You would…' and since this is ELU, can you say how you understand the difference there?

Comment: These verbs avoid, can't help, consider, dislike, feel like, finish, give up, miss, practise and suggest are followed by gerunds.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences:

> - You will enjoy working here
> - You will find it enjoyable to work here.

are both grammatically valid and both are quite natural. Their meanings are very similar.

The "working" form perhaps emphasizes that this is a process that will last for some time a bit more.

By the way, "working": here is not a gerund, it is a present participle. That means it is a verb form here. A gerund is a noun derived from a verb, not a verb form.

A pair of examples:

> Swimming  is excellent exercise and an interesting sport. [Gerund. "Swimming here is the name of an activity, a noun.]

> The man was swimming towards her rapidly. [Participle "swimming" here is an action verb.]

Comment: How is "working" not a gerund? It's the direct object of "love", no? Does "love" take a present-participle complement of some sort?

Comment: "By the way, "working": here is not a gerund, it is a present participle." One test is to translate into a language in which gerunds and present participles take different forms. Do you think "te encantará trabajando aquí" is the correct Spanish translation?

Comment: Working here is not enjoyable. How is that not a gerund? enjoy + verb+ing is most definitely a gerund.